# Time converting pipe for angular

Tags: javascript, angular6

I want the time stamp to be converted in HTML when i render it using angular object
I have an object where i get start and end time as 09:15:00 and 13:20:45
i want to convert them  to 09:15 am and 13:20 pm using pipe in html

```
<div>{{start_time}} {{end_time}}</div>

09:15:00 13:20:45
```

how can i achieve that using angular pipe because i cannot use date pipe here as that only works if we have date in the object
how can i achieve that using angular pipe because i cannot use date pipe here as that only works if we have date in the object

Can anyone help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customTimePipe'
})
export class CustomTimePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return moment(value,'HH:mm').format("HH:mm A");
  }
}
```

This is Pipe file

hereafter you have to use like this in HTML

```
<div>{{start_time | customTimePipe}} {{end_time | customTimePipe}}</div>
```

Hope this will solve you problem.

Comment: Here you have staticly defined 09:00:00, how can this is dynamic like accessee start time and end time in current time?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom 'time converting' [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes).

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import moment = require('moment');
@Pipe({name: 'datepipe'})
export class datepipe implements PipeTransform{

    transform(value:any, args:any){

        return moment(value,'HH:mm').format("HH:mm A");

    }

}
```

and use this pipe at the time of display.

```
{{start_time | datepipe}}  {{end_time | datepipe}}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-iyszmf)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to convert your timestamp to date as

```
new Date(timestamp)
```

and then try to use data PIPE